# usings a for loop to append to an empty object in r

Tags: r, for-loop

this may seem like a novice question, but I'm struggling to understand why this doesn't work.

```
answer = c()
for(i in 1:8){
  answer = c()
  knn.pred <- knn(data.frame(train_week$Lag2), data.frame(test_week$Lag2), train_week$Direction, k=i)
  test <- mean(knn.pred == test_week$Direction)
  append(answer, test)
}
```

I want the results 1-8 in a vector called answer.  it should loop through 8 times, so ideally a vector with 8 numbers would be my output.  When I run the for loop, I only get the final answer, meaning it isn't appending.  any help would be appreciated, sorry for the novice question, really trying to learn R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, please include a reproducible example in your question next time. See [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Second, you set `answer` to `c()` in the first line of your loop, so this happens in each iteration.

Third, `append`, just like almost all functions in R, does not modify its argument in place, but it returns a new object. So the correct code is:

```
answer = c()
for (i in 1:8){
  knn.pred <- knn(data.frame(train_week$Lag2), data.frame(test_week$Lag2), 
                  train_week$Direction, k = i)
  test <- mean(knn.pred == test_week$Direction)
  answer <- append(answer, test)
```

}

While this wasn't the question, I can't help noting that this is a very inefficient way of creating vectors and lists. It is an anti-pattern. If you know the length of the result vector, then allocate it, and set its elements. E.g

```
answer = numeric(8)
for (i in 1:8){
  knn.pred <- knn(data.frame(train_week$Lag2), data.frame(test_week$Lag2), 
                  train_week$Direction, k = i)
  test <- mean(knn.pred == test_week$Direction)
  answer[i] <- test
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting `answer` inside the for loop.  Try removing that line.  Also, append doesn't act on its arguments directly; it returns the modified vector.  So you need to assign it.

```
answer <- c()
for(i in 1:8){
  knn.pred <- knn(data.frame(train_week$Lag2), data.frame(test_week$Lag2), train_week$Direction, k=i)
  test <- mean(knn.pred == test_week$Direction)
  answer <- append(answer, test)
}
```